# How do I modify /etc/syslog.conf to send messages to specific files?

Tags: configuration, mail

How do I modify /etc/syslog.conf so that I would send all messages with "warn" priority, except those of type "mail" and "lpr" to /var/log/mywarnings.
I also have to send all messages of type "mail", except those with priority "err" to /var/log/mymail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man rsyslog.conf` will go a long way.

But to get you started:

```
*.=warn;mail.none;lpr.none    /var/log/mywarnings
```

This basically says all messages *equal* to level warn (`*.warn` would be warning or higher), but then exclude mail and lpr by asking for `.none`, to go to `/var/log/mywarnings`.

To exclude a priority and higher, use `!`. To exclude just one, it's `!=`. So:

```
mail.*;mail.!=err    /var/log/mymail
```

Comment: it was with mail.* in front. Thank you very much for the answer:)